# Building an old linux kernel on Ubuntu 22.04 error fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: linux, docker, compilation, kernel

I'm trying to run a research project on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop. The project requires building and running a `5.2.21` Linux kernel for the guest QEMU VM. I got the following error building Linux `5.2.21` on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop:

```
error: ‘-mindirect-branch’ and ‘-fcf-protection’ are not compatible
```

I realize it requires an older version of GCC. So I tried to compile the kernel using a gcc-8 docker container.

```
~/linux-src:
▶ docker run --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd):/code gcc-8 make -C /code
```

It shows errors:

```
  HOSTCC   /code/tools/objtool/fixdep.o
/code/tools/objtool//fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /code/tools/objtool//fixdep)
/code/tools/objtool//fixdep: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /code/tools/objtool//fixdep)
/code/tools/build/Makefile.build:96: recipe for target '/code/tools/objtool/fixdep.o' failed
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcc:8
#FROM ubuntu:18.04
#FROM gcc:8.5.0-buster
#FROM ubuntu:20.04
#ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential libssl-dev libncursesw5-dev git curl bc \
    flex bison libelf-dev make cmake
```

How this `version` GLIBC_2.33' not found` error can be fixed?

Any solutions to build an old Linux kernel on Ubuntu 22.04?

---

**Update**:

I can build the kernel by still mapping a host directory to the docker, but I need to clone the Linux kernel and build the Linux kernel within the docker container.

```
▶ docker run --rm -it --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd):/code gcc-8.5 bash
I have no name!@15e678776a72:/$ cd /code/test; git clone ... linux-x86
I have no name!@15e678776a72:/code/test/linux-x86$ time make -j20
... ...
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
```

It looks like the libc in the docker container is wrongly mapped in this case.

Comment: Explain why do you need to build an old Linux kernel, or why do you need to use Ubuntu 22.04 (and not some earlier or other Linux distribution) on it. Or why can't you use `schroot` ?*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  It's a research project, and I suppose to run this kernel using QEMU. I don't want to downgrade my laptop from Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Then why can't you use QEMU for your project?

Comment: I'm building the kernel for the QEMU guest. I don't want to run nested QEMU VMs.

Comment: This should go into your question. Without those details inside it I voted to close it.

Comment: I updated my question. Please let me know whether this makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to **build an old Linux kernel** on **recent Ubuntu 22.04 using a docker container**:

The `Dockerfile` (gcc-8.5 with all necessary kernel building dependencies):

```
FROM gcc:8.5.0-buster

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential libssl-dev libncursesw5-dev git curl bc \
    flex bison libelf-dev make cmake
```

Build the docker image:

```
▶ docker build -t gcc-8.5 -f Dockerfile .
```

Compile the old Linux kernel using gcc-8.5 from the docker container:

```
▶ ls     
linux-5.2.21
▶ docker run --rm -it --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd):/code gcc-8.5 bash
I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/$ cd /code/
I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/code$ ls
linux-5.2.21
I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/code$ cd linux-5.2.21/
I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/code/linux-5.2.21$ make defconfig; make kvm_guest.config
I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/code/linux-5.2.21$ time make -j20
... ...
  BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
Setup is 16060 bytes (padded to 16384 bytes).
System is 3269 kB
CRC 63e1012e
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)

I have no name!@48e2e4f878eb:/code/linux-5.2.21$ exit

▶ ls linux-x86/arch/x86/boot/bzImage 
linux-x86/arch/x86/boot/bzImage
```